# R data.frame with non-duplicate binomials

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I want to generate a 2 column data.frame but I would like to be sure than each binomial col1 - col2 is unique ...

```
n <- 1000
w <- seq(from = 0, to = n-1, by = 1)
x <- sample(0:99, n, replace=T)
y <- sample(0:99, n, replace=T)
input.df <- data.frame(xcor = sample(0:99, n, replace=T), y = sample(0:99, n, replace=T))
```

At this point it clearly doesn't work

```
summary(duplicated(input.df))

Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical     972      28       0
```

And I would like

```
summary(duplicated(input.df))

Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical     1000      0       0
```

Any trick is welcome !

Answer (score 2):

You were so close! You just need to use `duplicated` inside of brackets and make use you use `!` to specify **not** duplicated.

```
n <- 1000
w <- seq(from = 0, to = n-1, by = 1)
x <- sample(0:99, n, replace=T)
y <- sample(0:99, n, replace=T)
input.df <- data.frame(xcor = sample(0:99, n, replace=T), y = sample(0:99, n, replace=T))

summary(duplicated(input.df[!duplicated(input.df),]))
```

> ```
>    Mode   FALSE    NA's 
> logical     958       0
> ```

This is equivalent to `unique()` as Zheyuan mentioned.

```
final_data <- input.df[!duplicated(input.df),]
```

or

```
final_data <- unique(input.df)
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not finished ... maybe I haven't specified than I would like to have 1000 observations :-S